# What is the relation between change management, patch management and configuration management?

Tags: terminology

How are:

- change management
- patch management
- configuration management

related to each other and what is the security team's role in them?

Comment: Have you looked any of this up? These are all very well defined. This sounds like a classic homework question. Is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change Management:**

It is a plan to manage any change in your environment. Change Advisory Board  (CAB) members will review the changes to be made in your environment, do an impact analysis and approve/reject the final plan to implement the changes.

For example, if you want to upgrade all your servers to a new OS release,  you will bring that up in the CAB meeting, where all the stakeholders are present, and it will be reviewed and approved there.

**Patch Management:**

It is managing how you apply security patches in your environment. You need to document the deadlines to deploy patches based on the severity, who will be responsible for what etc.

For example, if a critical vulnerability is released in an OS that you are using in production, you will first notify about potential changes and the expected downtime to the CAB via Change Management and they will review the final and approve/reject the final plan for it based upon the consensus of all stakeholders.

**Configuration Management:**

It is a process for maintaining your complete digital infrastructure (workstation, servers, and software) in a desired, consistent state. You define a baseline and then apply it to all assets in scope.

Fore example, you define a baseline that all your workstations in your environment must have a minimum OS version of Windows 10. You'll do a impact analysis, how it might affect user experience, the costs involved, the effort required etc. The CAB  will review it and then approve/reject the final plan.

Comment: You do not cover the security team's role. Also, Config Mgmt maintains up-to-date documentation on the current state of assets, not just the baseline. So the changes to the patch levels on an asset get documented by the Config Mgmt process.

Comment: @Syed Anas Does the security team have a role in the impact analysis or the implementation of a change, or they are only involved when the change is a patch

Comment: @MohamedTalalLamouchi Ideally Change Advisory Board (CAB) must have an Infosec representative as well, so that they can review changes from security perspective. For patch management, they drive this change and do scoping, impact analysis etc. required to implement it. For others, they review changes and ensure best security practices to implement a change.